# ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: python, django, orm, annotations

I have this function

```
def with_items_photos(self):
    photos_subquery = Photo.objects.filter(
        object_id=OuterRef('pk'),
        content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(DeliveryItem)
    ).values('pk')

    return self.annotate(
        photos=Subquery(
            photos_subquery.annotate(
                photo_ids=ArrayAgg('pk')
            ).values('photo_ids')
        )
    )
```

I would like to get array of photo_ids for each item but get an error